# Search - Virus detection messages for crawl folder

Tags: search, crawling, anti-virus

One of my SharePoint environment is generating lots of detection messages when the crawler is running.
(At the moment there is no exclusion for this path for the virus scanner. Different topic)

**My problem is now:** How can I find this file (0x4261f_1.doc) in SharePoint without a url?

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Message:

```
Computer name: SPServername.MyDomain.de
Domain: MyDomain
Detection time(UTC time): 7/15/2016 5:56:54 AM Malware file path: file:_\\SPServername\gthrsvc_e343de44-5555-4ac3-a545-a7d4546f95ad-crawl-0\1f\0x4261f_1.doc
Remediation action: NoAction
Action status: Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. After some research,i figure out that we may have to be excluded from antivirus scanning when you use file-level antivirus software in SharePoint or you may see unexpected behavior.

[reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/952167/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-y)

Hope this help